# SharePoint dynamic employee directory

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, microsoft-graph, delve, people-directory

I'm looking for a solution to be able to create a dynamic employee directory.

Right now our company uses a SharePoint list that is filled by HR whenever a new employee comes on board, but this is quite inefficient. I've been trying to take advantage of things such as Delve in order to create a dynamic list, but I can't seem to find the way to do so.

For example, using the [Microsoft Graph API explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) I can send HTTP requests and retrieve most of the information I need from all the employees, but as of right now I can't seem to wrap my head around a solution using SharePoint or another Microsoft tool to create a dynamic list that would update whenever we added/removed a user through the admin panel, or an employee changed his Department field or even profile picture. A list that could fetch all these dynamically would be incredible.

I can't understand how this is not an built-in tool already considering on SharePoint lists you can already search for users inside your company when you create a "users" column with cards which retrieves a small thumbnail of the user's name and profile picture. If this is possible, al other information should be too.

I've also looked into [Microsoft's app marketplace](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/) which has a couple of apps, but none provide a solution to this.

I refuse to believe no one has done this before, there must be a way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend taking a look at the [People Directory web part](https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit/blob/master/documentation/components/wp-people-directory.md) that is available as part of the [SharePoint Starter Kit](https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit).

This is an open source solution provided by the PnP community and has a number of great web parts. It is free to use and fairly easy to deploy to your tenant.

Comment: Thank you, that's definitely another option. Looking into it, will update if it fulfils the requirements. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you have to create a custom [SPFx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) solution, which will fetch the user details and show them on page.

Check below SPFx samples created by community members. You can use these web parts as it is if it fulfills your requirements OR you can modify them as per your requirements after downloading.

1. [Microsoft Graph People Search](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-msgraph-peoplesearch) - This web part uses Microsoft Graph AI to get the user details. You can also filter the results using search query (For example to limit the results to particular department).
2. [People Directory](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-people-directory)

Comment: Looking at the People Directory as per Callum's suggestion as well. Will give feedback. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the options I found an app called "Employee Directory Pro" on the sharepoint marketplace which works great for what I was looking for right out of the box.
Thank you for the suggestions, but I found those to go a little bit too over my head for my current sharepoint knowledge.